# Swipe up for next and Swipe down for prev Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build a short news app like In Short App in Ionic 4. So basically I want to swipe up and down for the news. I had found a lot but all in vain. I didn't get anything from which I can achieve. Can anyone here help so that I can achieve my goal?

I dont want to do this with slider.

I had seen one plugin [hammerjs](https://hammerjs.github.io/). It will be appreciatable if anyone can create a demo for me.

Comment: You can do it .. If you can use little bit of math without any library now think about X and Y axix. Swipe up and Down happen on Y axix..0 to -n = swipe down 0 to n swipe up..Now use your brain

Comment: Can you please make one demo with images?

Comment: you have to try & post it if you facing any issues